# Firefox freezes while opening multiple tabs

Tags: firefox

I’m running Ubuntu 11.04 (32-bit version) on my laptop ASUS K42J just couple weeks and regularly having issues with Firefox – it has freezes sometimes when you opened multiple tabs.
The screen become to light cloudy appearance for about half a minute(or something like that), during this time you can’t do nothing.
I had looked through some posts there and found several similar issues, but mentioned tricks with changing of Firefox’ options (deleting history e.t.c.) doesn’t help. I’ll be appreciated for any help on mentioned matter

Comment: could you tell your computer specification? ;) your RAM and something. Thanks,

Comment: here you are:)   CPU: Intel Pentium P6200 2.13GHz, RAM: 2GB, videocard: AMD Radeon HD6470M

Comment: Have you seen this bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501158 may be it's help. Personal i use chromium ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for this link - it's very useful. I will look through it closely this evening. In a worst case I'll try another browser(for example Chromium) and will see how it looks in respect of mentioned issue.

Comment: If it's help for you, i will post as an answer and you can accept it ;) and it will help others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) to prevent unnecessary flash content from loading, [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) to prevent ad servers from being contacted, [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) to prevent tracking services like Google Analytics. Disable "Block reported attack sites" and "Block reported web forgeries" in Firefox Security preferences. This will improve responsiveness and reduce locking. [Optimizing](http://www.webgapps.org/tutorials/firefox/optimization/database-optimization) databases will probably help as well. Also check my [optimization and troubleshooting tutorials](http://www.webgapps.org/tutorials/firefox).

Make sure you have the latest driver for your video card installed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll check mentioned suggestions and keep you posted. I had bought my ASUS laptop just couple weeks ago and had freshly installed Natty, I think that I have the latest driver for video card AMD Radeon HD6470M, however I'll check it anyway

Comment: I have no info about your card, but it seems to me that ATI is a little bit problematic on Ubuntu. You might want to search the Ubuntu forums to find out the best driver for it or if there are any tweaks to improve it's performance and stability.

Comment: Actually I had used your in respect of mentioned add-ons (flashblock, AdBlock Plus, Ghostery and optimising databases - I turn them on), and so far it helps :)  during last 1hour I had no isuues with freesing

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501158)?

Personal i use 
[Chromium](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/chromium) [image: Install chromium] ;)

Comment: your "bug report" was helpful as well. There was mentioned about using adblock plus to filter the flash ads performance influence, what is quite effective I think

Comment: +1 by the way, I had downloaded Chromium for testing - it looks really fast.

Answer (score 1):

How many tabs do you have open when this happens? Try to use [tab grouping in Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-tab-groups) to decrease their number

Comment: 2-3 tabs in a time (as max). I guess it's not so much for freezing. I had used Firefox before on Windows 7 machine with no similar issues even while 10tabs were opened. OK, I'll try to use tab grouping, then will keep you informed

Comment: Tab Grouping (Panorama) doesn't improve performance, because tabs are still loaded in the background. However, in Firefox 6 when you use the Panorama feature, tabs are not loaded on startup, until you click the group. It helps to improve startup performance.

Comment: Tab grouping doesn't help :(